# Замена \ Python

Tags: python, replace

Как заменить символ `\` в Python?

При использовании `.replace('\', ' ')`  `\` выделяется и не позволяет реплейснуть

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать **экранирование** символа `\` с помощью него же:

```
print(r'sadsdsa\sdsadasd\asdsadsa'.replace('\\', ' '))
```

Вывод:

```
sadsdsa sdsadasd asdsadsa
```

Обычно ещё можно использовать `raw-string`, как у меня сделано для строки, в которой происходит замена, но, к сожалению, так не получится, если символ `\` последний в строке перед завершающей кавычкой.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ, который работает:

```py
переменная = 'Ваш текст тут'.replace('\\', 'На что заменить') # заменяет все "\" на то, что вам нужно
print(переменная) #вывод результата на экран
```

Пример:

```py
переменная = 'Тес\\т \\123'.replace('\\', '')
print(переменная)
```

Вывод в CMD:

```bsh
Тест 123
```

Надеюсь, я вам помог!